# How use/link .lib file as library using TASM assembler?

Tags: assembly, tasm, lib, irvine16

I make a project in assembly language and need to use .lib file. I use TASM assembler and I haven't success to run my program.

I've searched about linking .lib file using TASM, but all sources show me how linking .lib file using MASM. I found a short tutorial and I've been trying to use that from http://grail.cba.csuohio.edu/~jackie/cis335/tasmInfo.htm but I still can't run my program.

Comment: Not enough information. What happens on the screen (especially error messages)? What .lib do you want to integrate? Show your main .asm file or write a simple .asm file to demonstrate te problem. what does the command lines look like, resp. how do you assemble and link? Do you use a DOS emulator (e.g. DosBox)?

Comment: Yes, I use DOS emulator. I use .inc file in my main program and this .inc program use functions in .lib. I assemble my program by type "tasm myprogram.asm" and the eror messages is "illegal instruction" for every line in .inc file that use function in .lib file

Comment: Irvine16.lib / Irvine16.inc?

Answer (score 0):

`IRVINE16.INC` uses directives that TASM does not understand (e.g. PROTO). `IRVINE16.LIB` exports decorated names (e.g. `_WriteString@0`).

First you need to make the `IRVINE16.INC` readable:

- Change `.NOLIST` to `%NOLIST`
- Delete or comment out every line resp. block (two or three lines that obviously belong together) that contains the directive `PROTO`.
- Change every `STRUCT` to `STRUC` (CursorPosStruc, TimeRecord, FPU_ENVIRON)
- Change every `DWORD` to `DD`. Don't change `ALIGN DWORD`
- Change every `WORD` to `DW`
- Change every `BYTE` to `DB`

Now create an [8.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) text file with .inc extension. Let us name it `beeftasm.inc`:

```
EXTRN _Clrscr@0:PROC
EXTRN _Crlf@0:PROC
EXTRN _Delay@0:PROC
EXTRN _DumpMem@0:PROC
EXTRN _DumpRegs@0:PROC
EXTRN _GetCommandtail@0:PROC
EXTRN _GetMaxXY@0:PROC
EXTRN _GetMseconds@0:PROC
EXTRN _Gotoxy@0:PROC
EXTRN _IsDigit@0:PROC
EXTRN _Randomize@0:PROC
EXTRN _RandomRange@0:PROC
EXTRN _Random32@0:PROC
EXTRN _ReadHex@0:PROC
EXTRN _ReadInt@0:PROC
EXTRN _ReadChar@0:PROC
EXTRN _ReadFloat@0:PROC
EXTRN _ReadString@0:PROC
EXTRN _SetTextColor@0:PROC
EXTRN _ShowFPUStack@0:PROC
EXTRN _WaitMsg@0:PROC
EXTRN _WriteBin@0:PROC
EXTRN _WriteBinB@0:PROC
EXTRN _WriteChar@0:PROC
EXTRN _WriteDec@0:PROC
EXTRN _WriteHex@0:PROC
EXTRN _WriteHexB@0:PROC
EXTRN _WriteInt@0:PROC
EXTRN _WriteString@0:PROC
EXTRN _WriteFloat@0:PROC

EXTRN _Str_copy@4:PROC
EXTRN _Str_length@2:PROC
EXTRN _Str_compare@4:PROC
EXTRN _Str_trim@4:PROC
EXTRN _Str_ucase@2:PROC

Str_copy = cs:_Str_copy@4
Str_length = cs:_Str_length@2
Str_compare = cs:_Str_compare@4
Str_trim = cs:_Str_trim@4
Str_ucase = cs:_Str_ucase@2

Clrscr = cs:_Clrscr@0
Crlf = cs:_Crlf@0
Delay = cs:_Delay@0
DumpMem = cs:_DumpMem@0
DumpRegs = cs:_DumpRegs@0
GetCommandtail = cs:_GetCommandtail@0
GetMaxXY = cs:_GetMaxXY@0
GetMseconds = cs:_GetMseconds@0
Gotoxy = cs:_Gotoxy@0
IsDigit = cs:_IsDigit@0
Randomize = cs:_Randomize@0
RandomRange = cs:_RandomRange@0
Random32 = cs:_Random32@0
ReadHex = cs:_ReadHex@0
ReadInt = cs:_ReadInt@0
ReadChar = cs:_ReadChar@0
ReadFloat = cs:_ReadFloat@0
ReadString = cs:_ReadString@0
SetTextColor = cs:_SetTextColor@0
ShowFPUStack = cs:_ShowFPUStack@0
WaitMsg = cs:_WaitMsg@0
WriteBin = cs:_WriteBin@0
WriteBinB = cs:_WriteBinB@0
WriteChar = cs:_WriteChar@0
WriteDec = cs:_WriteDec@0
WriteHex = cs:_WriteHex@0
WriteHexB = cs:_WriteHexB@0
WriteInt = cs:_WriteInt@0
WriteString = cs:_WriteString@0
WriteFloat = cs:_WriteFloat@0
```

Aa small test program follows that calls all exported functions of `IRVINE16.LIB`:

```
; Name:     testirv.asm
; Assemble: tasm testirv
; Link:     tlink /3 testirv
; Run:      testirv Take whatever you need

INCLUDE IRVINE16.inc
INCLUDELIB Irvine16.lib

INCLUDE beeftasm.inc

.CODE
main PROC
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    call WhereXY
    mov WORD PTR [buf], dx
    call Clrscr
    call WhereXY
    mov WORD PTR [buf+2], dx
    lea dx, tClrscr
    call WriteString
    movzx eax, WORD PTR [buf+2]
    call WriteDec
    mov al, ' '
    call WriteChar
    movzx eax, WORD PTR [buf]
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf

    lea dx, tDumpMem
    call WriteString
    lea si, hello
    mov cx, 16
    mov bx, 1
    mov dx, OFFSET hello
    call DumpMem

    lea dx, tGetCommandtail
    call WriteString
    lea dx, buf
    call GetCommandtail
    call WriteString
    call Crlf

    lea dx, tWriteString
    call WriteString
    mov dx, OFFSET hello
    call WriteString
    call Crlf

    lea dx, tWriteChar
    call WriteString
    mov al, [hello]
    call WriteChar
    mov al, [hello+6]
    call WriteChar
    call Crlf

    lea dx, tWriteInt
    call WriteString
    mov eax, 1234567890
    call WriteInt
    mov al, ' '
    call WriteChar
    call WriteChar
    call WriteChar

    lea dx, tWriteDec
    call WriteString
    mov eax, 1234567890
    call WriteDec
    mov al, ' '
    call WriteChar
    call WriteChar
    call WriteChar

    lea dx, tWriteHex
    call WriteString
    mov eax, 1234567890
    call WriteHex
    call Crlf

    lea dx, tWriteHexB
    call WriteString
    mov eax, 1234567890
    mov ebx, 1
    call WriteHexB
    call Crlf

    lea dx, tWriteBin
    call WriteString
    mov eax, 1234567890
    call WriteBin
    call Crlf

    lea dx, tWriteBinB
    call WriteString
    mov eax, 1234567890
    mov ebx, 1
    call WriteBinB
    call Crlf

    lea dx, tGetMaxXY
    call WriteString
    call GetMaxXY
    movzx eax, dl
    call WriteDec
    mov al, ' '
    call WriteChar
    movzx eax, dh
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf

    lea dx, tGetMseconds
    call WriteString
    call GetMseconds
    mov DWORD PTR [buf], eax
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf

    call WhereXY
    push dx
    mov dh, 6
    mov dl, 40
    call Gotoxy
    lea dx, tGotoxy
    call WriteString
    mov bl, lightBlue
    lea si, hello2
    call WriteColoredString
    pop dx
    call Gotoxy

    lea dx, tIsDigit
    call WriteString
    lea si, tDecStr
J1:
    lodsb
    test al, al
    jz J2
    call IsDigit
    setz al
    or al, 30h
    call WriteChar
    jmp J1
J2:
    call Crlf

    lea dx, tRandom32
    call WriteString
    call Random32
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf

    lea dx, tRandomRange
    call WriteString
    mov ecx, 10
J3:
    mov eax, 1000
    call RandomRange
    call WriteDec
    mov al, ' '
    call WriteChar
    loop J3
    call Crlf

    lea dx, tRandomize
    call WriteString
    call Randomize
    mov ecx, 10
J4:
    mov eax, 1000
    call RandomRange
    call WriteDec
    mov al, ' '
    call WriteChar
    loop J4
    call Crlf

    lea dx, tStr_compare
    call WriteString
    push OFFSET tString2
    push OFFSET tString1
    call Str_compare
    setz al
    movzx eax, al
    call WriteDec
    mov al, ' '
    call WriteChar
    push OFFSET tString1
    push OFFSET tString1
    call Str_compare
    setz al
    movzx eax, al
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf

    lea dx, tStr_copy
    call WriteString
    mov ax, SEG buf
    mov es, ax
    push OFFSET buf
    push OFFSET tString1
    call Str_copy
    xor al, al
    mov cx, 0FFFFh
    lea di, buf
    repne scasb
    mov BYTE PTR [di-1], ' '
    push di
    push OFFSET tString2
    call Str_copy
    lea dx, buf
    call WriteString
    call Crlf

    lea dx, tStr_length
    call WriteString
    push OFFSET tString1
    call Str_length
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf

    lea dx, tStr_trim
    call WriteString
    mov eax, 'sss'
    mov DWORD PTR [tString2 + 3], 'sss'
    mov ax, ds
    mov es, ax
    push 's'
    push OFFSET tString2
    call Str_trim
    cld                     ; Restore the default direction (up)
    lea dx, tString2
    call WriteString
    call Crlf

    lea dx, tStr_ucase
    call WriteString
    push OFFSET tString1
    call Str_ucase
    lea dx, tString1
    call WriteString
    call Crlf

    lea dx, tWaitMsg
    call WriteString
    call WaitMsg

    lea dx, tDumpRegs
    call WriteString
    call DumpRegs

    lea dx, tShowFPUStack
    call WriteString
    finit
    fld1
    fldPI
    fldz
    fld fDouble
    fld fSingle
    call ShowFPUStack
    call Crlf

    lea dx, tWriteFloat
    call WriteString
    call WriteFloat
    call Crlf

    lea dx, tReadFloat
    call WriteString
    finit
    call ReadFloat
    call GotoPrevChar
    mov al, ' '
    call WriteChar
    call WriteFloat
    call Crlf

    lea dx, tReadString
    call WriteString
    lea dx, buf
    call ReadString
    push ax
    call GotoPrevChar
    mov al, ' '
    call WriteChar
    pop ax
    movzx eax, ax
    call WriteDec
    mov al, ' '
    call WriteChar
    lea dx, buf
    call WriteString
    call Crlf

    lea dx, tReadInt
    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    push eax
    call GotoPrevChar
    mov al, ' '
    call WriteChar
    pop eax
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf

    lea dx, tReadChar
    call WriteString
    call ReadChar
    push ax
    mov al, ' '
    call WriteChar
    pop ax
    call WriteChar
    call Crlf

    lea dx, tReadHex
    call WriteString
    call ReadHex
    mov esi, eax
    call GotoPrevChar
    mov al, ' '
    call WriteChar
    mov eax, esi
    call WriteBin
    mov al, ' '
    call WriteChar
    mov eax, esi
    call WriteInt
    mov al, ' '
    call WriteChar
    mov eax, esi
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf

    call Crlf
    call WaitMsg

    mov ax, red
    call SetTextColor
    lea dx, tSetTextColor
    call WriteString
    lea dx, hello1
    call WriteString
    call Crlf

    lea dx, tDelay
    call WriteString
    call GetMseconds
    mov ebx, eax
    mov eax, 100000
    call Delay
    call GetMseconds
    sub eax, ebx
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h

main ENDP

;---------------------------------------------------
WhereXY PROC
;
; Gets the cursor position on video page 0.
; Receives: nothing
; Returns: DH, DL = row, column
;---------------------------------------------------
    push ax
    push bx
    push cx
    mov ah, 3
    xor bh, bh
    int 10h
    pop cx
    pop bx
    pop ax
    ret
WhereXY ENDP

;---------------------------------------------------
WhatXY PROC
;
; Gets the character at cursor position on video page 0.
; Receives: nothing
; Returns: AH, AL = attribute, character
;---------------------------------------------------
    push bx
    mov ah, 8
    xor bh, bh
    int 10h
    pop bx
    ret
WhatXY ENDP

;---------------------------------------------------
GotoPrevChar PROC
;
; Gets the previous character from cursor position on video page 0.
; Receives: nothing
; Returns: Cursor on the video position right after the previous character
;---------------------------------------------------
    pusha
    call WhereXY
    xor dl, dl

    @@J1:
    call Gotoxy
    dec dh
    call WhatXY
    cmp al, 20h
    je @@J1
    inc dh

    mov bx, dx
    call GetMaxXY
    mov dh, bh

    @@J2:
    dec dl
    call Gotoxy
    call WhatXY
    cmp al, 20h
    je @@J2

    inc dl
    call Gotoxy

    popa
    ret
GotoPrevChar ENDP

;------------------------------------------------------
WriteColoredString PROC
;
; Writes a colored string
; Receives: DS:SI = Pointer to a zero terminated string
;           BL    = Color attribute (see Irvine16.inc)
; Returns: nothing
;-------------------------------------------------------

    pusha
    xor bh, bh

    @@nextchar:
    lodsb
    test al, al
    jz @@return

    mov cx, 1
    mov ah, 09h
    int 10h

    push bx
    mov ah, 3
    int 10h
    inc dl
    mov ah, 2
    int 10h
    pop bx

    jmp @@nextchar

    @@return:
    popa
    ret
WriteColoredString ENDP

.DATA
    hello db "Hello world",0
    hello1 db "Hello red world",0
    hello2 db "Hello blue planet",0
    tDecStr db " 2790000000 owns Donald Trump at least, but I only want a thank you",0
    fDouble dq 1.23456789
    fSingle dd 9.87654321
    tString1 db 'first',0
    tString2 db 'second',0
    buf db 80h DUP(0)

    tClrscr db "Clrscr: ",0
    tDelay db "Delay (10 seconds): ",0
    tDumpMem db "DumpMem: ",0
    tDumpRegs db "DumpRegs: ",0
    tGetCommandtail db "GetCommandtail: ",0
    tGetMaxXY db "GetMaxXY: ",0
    tGetMseconds db "GetMseconds: ",0
    tGotoxy db "Gotoxy: ",0
    tIsDigit db "IsDigit: ",0
    tRandom32 db "Random32: ",0
    tRandomize db "Randomize: ",0
    tRandomRange db "RandomRange: ",0
    tReadChar db "ReadChar: ",0
    tReadFloat db "ReadFloat: ",0
    tReadHex db "ReadHex: ",0
    tReadInt db "ReadInt: ",0
    tReadString db "ReadString: ",0
    tSetTextColor db "SetTextColor: ",0
    tShowFPUStack db "ShowFPUStack: ",0
    tStr_compare db "Str_compare: ",0
    tStr_copy db "Str_copy: ",0
    tStr_length db "Str_length: ",0
    tStr_trim db "Str_trim: ",0
    tStr_ucase db "Str_ucase: ",0
    tWaitMsg db "WaitMsg: ",0
    tWriteBin db "WriteBin: ",0
    tWriteBinB db "WriteBinB: ",0
    tWriteChar db "WriteChar: ",0
    tWriteDec db "WriteDec: ",0
    tWriteFloat db "WriteFloat: ",0
    tWriteHex db "WriteHex: ",0
    tWriteHexB db "WriteHexB: ",0
    tWriteInt db "WriteInt: ",0
    tWriteString db "WriteString: ",0

END main
```